# WP8 passing Geometry Item to Code behind to add to Path.Data type causes XamlParseException

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I've encountered an issue when trying to pass a `Geometry` item to the code behind of a `UserControl` element. I get a `XamlParseexception` when I try to set a `Path` elements `Data` attribute to this `Geometry` item.

Here is a part of my code in the code behind

```
    void CardBack_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Header.Text = _title;
        Text_run.Text = _title;
        Image.Data = setGeometry(AppResources.SECURITY_IMAGE_DATA); //this is where i am having the issue
        Cdescrption.Text = _description;
    }
```

`Image` refers to my path created here is the xaml for the Path element

```
 <Path x:Name="Image" Margin="30,20,30,10"    VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

I left the implementation of "setGeometry()" out as it does return a Geometry element and there doesn't seem to be an issue with this method?

`AppResources.SECURITY_IMAGE_DATA` is basically a string of co-ords that I convert to a `Geometry` instance.

If anyone could help me out here id appreciate it. Thanks

UPDATED

heres setGeometry() its a total hack but iam all out of ideas here

```
    private Geometry setGeometry(string sentData)
    {
       Path path = XamlReader.Load("<Path Data='" + sentData + "' />") as Path;
       return path.Data;
    }
```

At least i know if i do it this way i definitely have the correct object type.

Still stuck on this! pretty anoying when all i want to do is ad the Data to a Path

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:-

```
var geometry = Application.Current.Resources["SECURITY_IMAGE_DATA"]; // SECURITY_IMAGE_DATA should be a string or string type object, that have a resource name.
Image.Data = setGeometry(geometry);
```

Comment: I have SECURITY_IMAGE_DATA stored as a string. this didn't work for me

Comment: If it is a string then ....["SECURITY_IMAGE_DATA"] and then cast it to the type you want. Can you share the setGeometry code so we can help you?

Comment: Ill put up SetGeometry but its a total hack. not happy with it but i need to get this thing done.

Comment: You can put only the method and its signature.

Comment: the help is really appreciated. thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: Can you test this:- var geometry = (string)Application.Current.Resources["SECURITY_IMAGE_DATA"]; and add a breakpoint on this line to check the result.

Comment: its this line is giving me the error.                                 "Path path = XamlReader.Load("<Path Data='" + data + "' />") as Path;"

Comment: You are implementing XamlReader wrongly. Look at MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: damn it! still stuck! aaaaahhhh!